# Which one has the "Telepathic Kiss" power: Hana or Daichi?

Tags: captain-earth

In the ending of the series, Daichi kisses Hana, and Puck is surprised to see they are doing a telepathic kiss between them.

Since that power works both ways, it's hard to pinpoint **who** has the power (because it is activated even if unwilling).

So, which one of the lovey doveys has the telepathic kiss power? Hana or Daichi?

Hana is biologically engineered from the Planetary Gears' royalty DNA, so she might be the one.

Daichi has just [prestige-classed into "Badass Protagonist"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.../TookALevelInBadass) because the [stakes were raised](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DifficultySpike) and he had to beat the [final boss](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrueFinalBoss) alone. If he could learn how to teleport his Mecha in such a short time, why not?

And please [back your answer with sources](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226388/should-i-add-information-from-external-sources-into-my-answers), if possible. Lets keep it the least subjective possible.

> P.S.: In advance, I apologize for any time lost [visiting TvTropes](http://xkcd.com/609/). Always mouse over links before clicking away.

Comment: IMO it was Daichi, because Hana was under control of Puck, and Daichi made the move.

Answer (score 1):

Well, earlier in the series, Hana was worried about Daichi kissing her. She said something along the lines of "I was worried you'd hate the real me". Thus, she knows that the kiss between them would be telepathic. We can assume from this that She is the one with said power.

and as for Stevebot's answer, the Planetary gears Princess was under control of a mind-transfer machine when she was telepathic-kissed, and saw her foster mother's evil intentions. So telepathic kiss works despite mind-control